# How can I create temporary variables in my .gitconfig?

Tags: git

It sometimes happens that I have a long and string in an alias's argument list; the full path to diff-highlight, say, or a really long and confusing pretty-format string.

I would like to put these strings in a temporary variable so that I can do something like the following, which I find much more readable than inlining:

```
[alias]
    FMT_OF_DEATH="somethinghideouslylongandunreadable"
    hist = log --pretty=format:$FMT_OF_DEATH --graph --date=short
```

Can I do that, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

[Edit] See below for details, but it turns out that for `--pretty=format`, this has long been built in (since Git version 1.7.10).

Given `--pretty=format:name`, `git log` will look up the *name* in the `[format]` section.  So you just need to run `git log --pretty=format:death --graph --date=short`, with your format-of-death in `format.death`.  The names are also expanded recursively, so you can give `format.death = format.death1 format.death2` in your configuration, with `format.death1` and `format.death2` expanding to `%...` directives (and any literal strings you like as well).

For things that are not format strings, you still have to do it the hard way, though.

#### The hard way

To do this the hard way, you must invoke the shell and have the shell invoke `git config --get` (or equivalent) to expand the inner part.  As a result, you wind up needing to be careful about whether the shell might expand any *outer* part as well.  Fortunately, with Git, many items don't get shell-munched.  (This is not always true with other programs that work similarly.)  Hence, continuing with the format idea—you'd want something different for other commands:

```
[format]
    death = somethinghideouslylongandunreadable   
[alias]
    hist = !git log "--pretty=format:"\"$(git config --get format.death)\" \
      --graph --date=short
```

Note that this can be more flexible, as you can pre-encode however many deadly formats you like, and then select one using a command-line argument.  However, at this point the alias itself is getting sufficiently complex that you might just want to write it as a shell script instead, where you can use `git-sh-setup` and its various features:

```
[format]
    death1 = ...
    death2 = ...
```

plus:

```
#! /bin/sh
# git-hist: run git log with --pretty=format:<fmt> where <fmt>
# is extracted via "git config --get format.whatever", where
# the "whatever" part is an argument

USAGE="which-format [args passed through to git log]"

. git-sh-setup

case $# in
0) usage;;
*) fmt=$(git config --get format."$1") ||
     die "hist: no \"format.$1\" found (check git configuration)"
   shift;;
esac

exec git log --pretty=format:"$fmt" --graph --date=short "$@"
```

With this script somewhere in your `$PATH`, you can just run `git hist foo` to get your output in the `format.foo` format.  You can override the `--date` and log from branch `zorg` with `git hist foo --date=long zorg`, and so on.

But since it's all built in, you might as well do it the easy way!